# Meteor: Why am I losing my data context by switching function() { } to () => { }?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

So I'm experimenting with ES6, installed the grigio:babel package, and am starting to go through my es5 code and update it to some of the new ES6 syntax when I ran into a problem.

Originally my template helpers looked something like this:

```
Template.exampleTemplateName.helpers({
   exampleHelper: function() {
      //returns an array from Mongo Collection
   }
});
```

which is used in a Blaze each loop as such

```
{{#each exampleHelper}}
{{/each}}
```

As you'd expect, all of my event handlers for the elements in this event loop had access to the fields in the Mongo Collection that is being returned by `exampleHelper` via the `this` keyword. `this.exampleField` would return exactly what I'd expect it to return.

So now's the point at which I started to update to ES6. For some reason the following syntax breaks the data context, so instead of `this` returning what you'd expect, it returns `Window` instead:

```
Template.exampleTemplateName.helpers({
    exampleHelper() {
        //returns an array from Mongo Collection
    }
});
```

The above was my first attempt, then I tried:

```
Template.exampleTemplateName.helpers({
    exampleHelper: () => {
        //returns an array from Mongo Collection
    }
});
```

So I ran the above ES6 code through Babeljs's online translator and received the following, which is obviously incorrect as I don't want a named function:

```
Template.exampleTemplateName.helpers({
     exampleHelper: function exampleHelper() {}
});
```

Can someone tell me what the correct syntax should look like?

Comment: IIUC this is actually a *feature*: arrow functions do not have their own `this`, they close over `this` like it's any other variable from the parent context.

Comment: So this would be a situation where arrow functions _should not_ be used?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I didn't post that as an answer because I'm not sure of it, though.

Comment: Why would you need to refer to `this` within `exampleHelper` which is just returning a set of data from Mongo? Since you have `{{#each exampleHelper}}`, `this` will not refer to items within that array.

Comment: I do not refer to `this` within `exampleHelper`, I refer to `this` in all the event handlers that are bound to elements generated by the {{#each}}. It's incredibly convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what the correct syntax should look like?

Your original code was totally fine. You don't have to abuse the features and use them just in order to use them, save few keystokes, etc. In this case normal anonymous function is what you should use.

The reason why you have this confusion with `this` pointing to global object, is because this is how arrow functions work: they have *lexical* `this`, not *dynamic*. This means that `this` reference is bound statically to function context at the time of the function creation (in your case it was `window`), and not resolved dynamically at runtime.

Comment: In fact the arrow function doesn't even save keystrokes, the method definition is shorter (*and* works correctly).

Answer (score 2):

This code will not work (it will show the window object):

```
Template.homePage.helpers({
  exampleHelper: function () {
    return [
      {text: 'this'}, {text: 'that'}, {text: 'the other thing'}
    ];
  },

  process: () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

Because when you use `=>` syntax, it wants to do something like this:

```
var self = this;

process(function () {
  doSomethingWith(self);
});
```

So in this case, `this` does indeed equal `window`. The solution is to not use `=>` in this scenario.